# select and convert column names in pyspark data frame

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark`. I want to select some columns from that `data frame` and converts them to lowercase.

```
# selecting columns after the second column in data frame df as a list:
df1 = df.schema.names[2:]

# convert the list to lowercase
test_list = [c.lower() for c in df1]
```

I am able to achieve what I want but I would like to do this in a single step instead of two steps

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
test_list = [c.lower() for c in df.schema.names[2:]]
```